# How to detect if a text is base64 encoded or is a plain text.? ( C, Linux)

Tags: c, linux, shell, email

I'm having issues with an email client that I'm working on, basically when I fetch an email I have to decode it via base64 tools, I have automated the process by directly downloading unseen new emails and then it is auto decoded and gives me the actual email text or attachment, but the problem is that some emails to my gmail accounts are in plain text and html which when automatically decoded gives me just empty files instead of the plain text.

So i want to know if there is any way by which i can detect the text format before trying to decode it, because decoding a simple plain text or html actually corrupts the data.

This would help me decode only those emails which is base64 encoded instead of decoding every and all emails that i fetch from my gmail account.

I'm on linux, doing it in C and shell.

Would really appreciate your help.

> Edit: I fetch only one unseen email (Body, one or two sections
>   excluding headers) at a time, but after fetching i have to decode it
>   to a plain text or a multimedia file, it works fine, but one email in
>   10 is actually not base64 encoded and is a simple plain text while my
>   program decodes every email it fetches, so that one email which is
>   plain text and not base64 encoded ends up as some empty file...
>
> So I want to skip decoding that email which is simple plain text and
>   not base64 text.

Comment: Look at the email headers

Comment: Besides the headers, the "text" in a base64-encoded message doesn't really contain much whitespace. A "normal" text would have some, as well as some punctuation characters (usually). You could also check the length if it's multiple of four (including padding of `'='` at the end). Even combined it's not a 100% certain way to detect it, but it's definitely a hint.

Comment: I need a better solution than downloading all the headers and then deciding on that matter whether to decode or not, that's computationally very expensive.

Comment: Make a histogram. In base64, the 64 possible characters are distributed uniformly.

Comment: Can you please try to be more specific about the header-thing... Do you want to fetch *all* messages or only those that are (or are not) base64 encoded? If you want to fetch all messages then you need the headers as well, and parsing them is not that computationally expensive on a relative modern system. And even if you only want to fetch some messages, getting the headers and deciding which message bodies to fetch is way better than to fetch all messages and try to decode them.

Comment: *I need a better solution than downloading all the headers and then deciding on that matter whether to decode or not, that's computationally very expensive.*  You've already downloaded the entire email, haven't you? And why do you think it's computationally intensive to read the headers? Have you benchmarked how much time it takes to read headers and compared it to how much time it takes to download the email itself?  And even if it is computationally intensive, I don't know how you can possibly process an email *without* parsing the headers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Nope, not all, I fetch only one unseen email at a time, but after fetching i have to decode it to a plain text or a multimedia file, it works fine, but 1 email in 10 is actually not base64 encoded while my program decodes every email it fetches, so that one email which is plain text and not base64 encoded ends up as some corrupts data or empty file...Basically i want to skip decoding that email which is simple plain text and not base64 text.

Comment: @wildplasser, that's only true if the data that's been base64-encoded is compressed or random.

Comment: To be more simple, I want to detect whether a string or a text file is a base64 encoded text or plain text.

Comment: If you see any characters outside the 64 characters used to encode Base-64, plus = for padding, plus newline, then you can be fairly sure it isn't Base-64.  If you don't see any tabs or spaces, it is not (normal) plain text.  The smaller the fragment, the easier it is to confuse plain text with Base64.  Indeed, you may not be able to distinguish reliably: a line containing just `Apoplexy`, for example, could give someone apoplexy if they're trying to decide whether that's plain text or Base-64.  It's a weird character sequence when decoded as Base-64 (0x02 0x9A 0x29 0x95 0xEC 0x72) but valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I implemented this technique , but it is not a solution , it is easily confused with words like Hellolol , Apoplexy etc....Wasted my time on that, I'm stuck.

Comment: The problem is that other than looking at surrounding information — headers etc — there's nothing to tell you whether an 8-character word is a word or Base64 encoded data.  The problem is irresolvable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I moved to get it done via headers fields, but new problem arises, see here: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765611/libcurl-imaps-doesnt-returns-header-field-content-transfer-encoding-or-conte)