# libcurl imaps doesn't returns Header Field "Content-Transfer-Encoding" or "Content-Type"

Tags: c, linux, email, libcurl, gmail-imap

I have been trying to detect encoding of an email manually, to see whether the email that i have just fetched needed to be base64 decoded or not, but that wasn't a complete solution.

So now I'm trying to download the headers (fields) of an email first, check them what kind of email it is and then proceed to decoding it with base64 in case the header says that it is a base64 encoded email or just skip it if it is a plain text or HTML text.

The problem is that the libcurl commands for fetching these fields doesn't really work, most of the time the "Content-Type" returns just an empty string or says that it is a multipart/alternative but when i check the email manually it is just a plain text which obviously doesn't need to be decoded.??

**"Content-Type"** field multipart/alternative usually have different parts like text, html, base64 encoded text, attachments etc.

In cases of multipart/alternative the **"Content-Transfer-Encoding"** field doesn't return anything at all, and this is the most important header field for me to know what it contains.

**My imaps request to Gmail account looks like this:**

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX;UID=33;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%%20(Content-Transfer-Encoding%%20Subject%%20From%%20Content-Type)");
```

**Which returns this:**

> Subject: my subject 
>   From: myname  
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a114930a049c6da05dskdls9"

As you can see it doesn't returns the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" field.

This email actually contains the word "Yup" only, so it is a plain text and no attachments, when checked by clicking on the "show original" message in browser.

Sys info:
Linux, C , libcurl, gmail

Comment: Can you show the raw IMAP commands that libcurl is sending, and their responses? Neither IMAP nor libcurl should be injecting `multipart/alternative` into plain text emails, so it has to already exist in the email to begin with. Just because an email displays as plain text does not mean it is just plain text. IMAP recognizes MIME and can parse and represent the individual MIME pieces of an email. You are asking for an email's top-level headers only, not any MIME information that may be nested below the top level. You need to retrieve an email's `BODYSTRUCTURE` to know its actual composition...

Comment: ... `Content-Transfer-Encoding` does not usually apply to `multipart` MIME parts, only nested `text` parts and attachments. So you need to discover where those are located within the email's structure before you can then retrieve them individually with IMAP.  Otherwise, you have to retrieve the email's entire raw data and parse it yourself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right, **multipart/alternative** have nested parts, but i don't know how do i get header fields from the nested parts.?? like the **Content-Type** or **Content-Transfer-Encoding** fields  of a nested part of an email.....I have seen that these nested parts do have a **Content-Transfer-Encoding** and **Content-Type** fields but I don't know the way to retrieve them, and the general command 'SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(Content-Type%20Content-Transfer-Encoding)' returns only the **Content-Type** with a value "**multipart/alternative**" .

Comment: as I told you, you have to retrieve the `BODYSTRUCTURE` of the email instead of its `HEADER.FIELDS`. That will tell you which pieces are available, how they are nested, and how they are identified. Then you can retrieve the `HEADER.FIELDS` of a particular part by including its identifier